# How change of privileges on google account affect API access?

Tags: google-oauth, admin, crud, google-api-php-client, privileges

I have a google admin account where I configured OAuth2.0 on several projects. 
What would happen if this account were changed to zero admin privileges? These projects would still be able to do operations like create/update/delete users?

Comment: You could try to setup a test environment.

Answer (score 2):

I think for what you are describing, you would see a 403 error if you removed roles from an account that had privileges to make changes within your org.

The project does not define privileges. The Admin Console grants access to projects by enabling the appropriate API and assigning scopes to a client-id.

Assuming a g suite account was created with roles to make changes to primary domain, ( assigned roles, such as "Groups Admin" and "User Management") and those roles were removed, you would likely see something like:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with  message '{
"error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"
 }
}
```